# Firebase concurrent modifications and transaction solution

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an android app(game) which matches 2 people and let them play. I am using firebase realtime database for this and have written necessary code for this at Node.js. At my database when someone clicks on "online button" it triggers firebase function and makes the players status waiting (status: waiting) and match him/her with another player whose status is also "waiting" if opperation is succefull node.js updates "rakip" node with opponents username for both player for further actions.

However my concern is when 2 users search for opponents at the same time (lets say user A and B) there might be a bad situation, for example  user A matches with B and user B matches with C. How can i prevent this to happen? How can i stop B's search (node.js action) as soon as his/her status changes?

Thanks in advance.

My realtime firebase database is like this:

```
My-project-name
  users
    sinan
      atilansayi: ""
      gal: false
      lose: 0
      rakip: "hakan"
      rakipsallama: ""
      sayilar: "4567"
      sonuc: ""
      status: "on"
      turn: false
      win: 1
    hakan
      atilansayi: 5678
      gal: false
      lose: 1
      rakip: "sinan"
      rakipsallama: "7559|13238436"
      sayilar: 7559
      sonuc: "-"
      status: "on"
      turn: true
      win: 0
    mehmet
      atilansayi: 9000
      gal: "no"
      lose: 0
      rakip: "hakan"
      rakipsallama: 3333
      sayilar: 7000
      sonuc: "+"
      status: "on"
      turn: false
      win: 0
```

My Node.js file is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sayi = functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}/status").onWrite(event => {
    var status = event.data.val();
    var user = event.data.ref.parent.key;
    if (status ==="waiting") {
        const events = admin.database().ref('users');
        const query =events.orderByChild('status').equalTo('waiting').limitToFirst(2);
        query.on("value",
         function(data) {
            var waitinggameusers= data.val();
            var keys = Object.keys(waitinggameusers);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {            
                var key = keys[i];
                if(key!==user){
```

//////////////THIS IS THE PART WHERE PROBLEM MAY OCCUR /////////////////

```
                    admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/rakip").set(key);
                    admin.database().ref("/users/"+key+"/rakip").set(user);
                    admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/status").set("on");
                    admin.database().ref("/users/"+key+"/status").set("on");
                    return console.log("bbbb"+" "+key);
```

//////////////THIS IS THE PART WHERE PROBLEM MAY OCCUR /////////////////

```
                }               
            }
        }, sorunlu);
    }
});
exports.sayiat = functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}/atilansayi").onWrite(event => {
    var sallanansayi ="";
    var rakibinsayisi ="";
    var res = event.data.val();
    if(res===""){
        return true;
    }
    var res2 = res.split("|");
    sallanansayi += res2[0];
    sallanansayi2=sallanansayi;
    var user = event.data.ref.parent.key;
    var sonuc ="";
    var artilar ="";   
    return admin.database().ref('users/'+user+'/rakip').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
       var rakip = snapshot.val();
       console.log("Rakip: "+rakip);
       return admin.database().ref('users/'+rakip+'/sayilar').once('value').then(function(sayisinibul){          
        rakibinsayisi += sayisinibul.val();
            for (i = 0; i < sallanansayi2.length; i++) {
                if(sallanansayi2.charAt(i)===rakibinsayisi.charAt(i)){
                    sonuc +="+";
                    artilar += i;
                }
            }
            console.log("Sonuç(sadece artılar): "+sonuc);
            console.log("Artıların yerleri: "+artilar);
            console.log("Artiların sayısı: "+artilar.length);            
            for (i = 0; i < artilar.length; i++) {
                sallanansayi2 = sallanansayi2.slice(0, artilar.charAt(i)) +"a"+ sallanansayi2.slice(Number(artilar.charAt(i))+1);
                rakibinsayisi = rakibinsayisi.slice(0, artilar.charAt(i)) +"b"+ rakibinsayisi.slice(Number(artilar.charAt(i))+1);
            }
            console.log("Atılan sayı: "+sallanansayi2);
            console.log("Rakibin sayısı: "+rakibinsayisi);           
            for (i = 0; i < sallanansayi2.length; i++) {   
                if(rakibinsayisi.indexOf(sallanansayi2.charAt(i))!==-1){
                    sonuc += "-";
                    var x= rakibinsayisi.indexOf(sallanansayi2.charAt(i));
                    rakibinsayisi= rakibinsayisi.slice(0,x)+"y"+rakibinsayisi.slice(x+1);
                    sallanansayi2= sallanansayi2.slice(0,i)+"x"+sallanansayi2.slice(i+1);
                }
            }
            var randomnumber = getRndInteger(1,100000000);  
            if(sonuc===""){
                sonuc ="x";
            }else if(sonuc==="++++"){
                admin.database().ref('users/'+user+'/win').transaction(count => {
                    if (count === null) {
                        return count = 1
                    } else {
                        return count + 1
                    }
                })
                admin.database().ref('users/'+rakip+'/lose').transaction(count => {
                    if (count === null) {
                        return count = 1
                    } else {
                        return count + 1
                    }
                })
                admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/turn").set(false);
                admin.database().ref("/users/"+rakip+"/turn").set(true);
                admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/sonuc").set(sonuc+"|"+randomnumber);
                return admin.database().ref("/users/"+rakip+"/rakipsallama").set(sallanansayi+"|"+randomnumber);
                //return admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/gal").set(true);
            }
            console.log("Rakibin sayısı(son): "+rakibinsayisi);
            console.log("Sallanan sayı(son): "+sallanansayi2);
            console.log("Sonuç: "+sonuc);                   
            admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/turn").set(false);
            admin.database().ref("/users/"+rakip+"/rakipsallama").set(sallanansayi+"|"+randomnumber);
            admin.database().ref("/users/"+rakip+"/turn").set(true);
            return admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/sonuc").set(sonuc+"|"+randomnumber);
        });        
    });
});


function sorunlu(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong.");
    return console.log(error);
}
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}
```

/////

Frank's database rule advice combined with read/write access

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
        "status": {
              ".validate": "newData.val() === 'on' || data.val() === 'off'|| data.val() === 'waiting'"
            },
         "rakip": {
               ".validate": 
        "newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val()).child('rakip').val() === $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you have a condition where only one user can modify the data, have a look at [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) to see if they can solve the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , there is an example like this for number increment var upvotesRef = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/upvotes");
upvotesRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
}); but i couldnt figure out how to modify return section something like if(current_value !== "on"){ return admin.database().ref("/users/"+key+"/rakip").set(user); } be ok?

Comment: Aha, I now see that you use transactions in your code. There is a bit much going on in there for me to grok. Is there any way to [reduce the code to the minimum that reproduces what you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It'll be much easier to help with that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sayi function at the beginning starting with "exports.sayi = functions.database.ref..." line changes nodes (status and rakip) other parts of code not much relevant about my question. User's status node and opponenets status node (which is found from query) becomes "on" and found opponent name is written in rakip node and opponents rakip node is changed to users name.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to enforce consistency here seems to be with a multi-location update. With a multi-location update you send multiple updates to the server in one call, and the server enforced that either all of the writes happen, or none of them happens.

Your code snippet:

```
admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/rakip").set(key);
admin.database().ref("/users/"+key+"/rakip").set(user);
admin.database().ref("/users/"+user+"/status").set("on");
admin.database().ref("/users/"+key+"/status").set("on");
```

Can be rewritten as a single multi-location update with:

```
var updates = {};
updates["/users/"+user+"/rakip"] = key;
updates["/users/"+key+"/rakip"] = user;
updates["/users/"+user+"/status"] = "on";
updates["/users/"+key+"/status"] = "on";
admin.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Now on the server you can use security rules to ensure the original data hasn't been modified.

If you can only set the status to `"on"` if it's currently `"off"`, you'd validate on `/users/$user/status`:

```
".validate": "newData.val() === 'on' && data.val() === 'off'"
```

And the trickier one: to ensure you can only set the `"rakip"` value if that user's value is also set validate `/users/$user/rakip`:

```
".validate": "newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val()).child('rakip').val() === $user"
```

Combined these are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        "status": {
          ".validate": "newData.val() === 'on' && data.val() === 'off'"
        },
        "rakip": {
           ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().child(newData.val()).child('rakip').val() === $user"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frank, So i edited your database rules including read/write access is it true? Sorry i dont know firebase database rules very well.